# Angular broadcast event causing listener to execute two times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-broadcast

I have a method in a service which broadcasts an event and one controller has subscribed for it.

When broadcast happens the subscriber handler executes two times.
Below is the setup:

```
//Broadcaster

function (Id1, Id2, Id3) {
    var requestObj = {"ID1": Id1, "ID3": Id3};
    $http.post(url, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    })
    .success(function (response) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('myevent');
    }).error(function (response) {
    });
}
================================================================

//subscriber

$scope.$on('myevent', function () {
    console.log($dialog); // Executes two times
});
```

I am not able to rectify the cause. Is there something else which can make the difference. 
Thanks.

Comment: This could very well be due to duplicate controllers loaded for your view. A common reason for duplicate controller is due to controller declared in the route in `$routeProvider` configuration and also in the view html using `ng-controller`.

Comment: @Chandermani: Thanks. Exactly this was the issue, Does is matter which one I use? because in the `subscriber` I was opening a `dialog` and both the executions were opening dialogs from different templates.

Comment: I don't think it matters. I would add it as answer, so that the question can be marked answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out there was multiple declaration of controller which was causing duplicate $on to trigger.

One of the common reason this happens is due to controller declared in the `$routeProvider` configuration and also in the view html using `ng-controller`

Comment: That's exactly it. Easy fix.